# Property for bounding matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, matrix-exponential

Wikipedia states in the exponential map section about the exponential of a matrix that for any matrices $X$, $Y$ it holds that $\|e^{X+Y}-e^{X}\| \leq \|Y\|e^{\|X\|} e^{\|Y\|}$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes an arbitrary matrix norm. I am trying to prove it since I cannot find it as a reference somewhere. Using the series I can't say that the result is the desired one.

Comment: Do you have a further response to the answers below? (Please look at [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers)).

Answer (score 5):

For any $n\times n$ matrices $X_1$ and $X_2$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    e^{X_1+X_2}-e^{X_1}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\,[(X_1+X_2)^k-X_1^k] \\ 
    &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\;
    \sum_{(j_1,\dots,j_k)\in\{1,2\}^k\setminus\{(1,\dots,1)\}}\;
    \prod_{i=1}^k X_{j_i}, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so that (assuming that the matrix norm is an operator norm)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \|e^{X_1+X_2}-e^{X_1}\|
    &\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\;
    \sum_{(j_1,\dots,j_k)\in\{1,2\}^k\setminus\{(1,\dots,1)\}}\;
    \prod_{i=1}^k \|X_{j_i}\| \\ 
    &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\;
    \sum_{m=1}^k \binom km \|X_1\|^m \|X_2\|^{k-m} \\  
    &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\;[(\|X_1\|+\|X_2\|)^k-\|X_1\|^k] \\ 
    &=e^{\|X_1\|+\|X_2\|}-e^{\|X_1\|} \\ 
    &\le \|X_2\| e^{\|X_1\|+\|X_2\|}.\quad\Box 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

---

As shown in [Christian Remling's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466890/36721), the condition that the matrix norm is an operator norm cannot be dropped.

Comment: At least according to the usage suggested here, a "matrix norm" is just a norm on the vector space of matrices; it need not satisfy $\| AB\|\le \|A\|\, \|B\|$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: And the source mentioned by the OP does refer to this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Thank you for your comments. Indeed, I thought this could only be true for operator matrix norms -- as your example now shows.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you for the clarification Prof. Pinelis. So considering that the \| AB\|\le \|A\|\, \|B\| property holds only then this proof is strong . Am I correct ?

Comment: @KatsanikJr : Yes, indeed. On the other hand, as shown by Christian Remling, this condition cannot be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

The wikipedia article you refer to is [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map) This indeed states that
$$
\|e^{X+Y}-e^X\| \le \|Y\| e^{\|X\|}e^{\|Y\|} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
for any "matrix norm", and, according to the link that is given, this term just means an arbitrary norm on the vector space of matrices, not necessarily satisfying $\|AB\| \le \| A\|\,\|B\|$.

In this generality, the statement is false. Take
$$
X=0, \quad Y=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} .
$$
Then $e^Y =\cosh 1 + Y\sinh 1$, so if we define a norm as
$$
\left\| \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \right\| = |a|+|d|+\epsilon (|b| + |c|)
$$
and take $\epsilon>0$ small, then the RHS of \eqref{1} will be small while the LHS is $\ge 2(\cosh 1 -1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Indeed I was working on this property considering square matrices nxn. So since my intention is to use this property and prove it that it holds at least for one norm (i.e. L2 norm) and I want |AB| <= |A||B| to hold, the proof seems strong although it may not hold for a more general case as explained above